# setPosition of Sprite onUpdate in AndEngine

Tags: java, android, sprites, andengine

I am trying to get a "highlighter" circle to follow around a sprite, but I am having trouble, I thought I could use the onUpdate method that's available to me in SequenceEntityModifier but it's not working for me. Here is my code:

```
    // make sequence mod with move modifier
    SequenceEntityModifier modifier = new SequenceEntityModifier(myMovemod) {

        @Override
        protected void onModifierFinished(IEntity pItem) {
            // animation finished
            super.onModifierFinished(pItem);
        }

        public float onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed, IEntity pItem) {

            highlighter.setPosition(player2.getX() - highlighterOffset, player2.getY() - highlighterOffset);
            return pSecondsElapsed;
        } 

    };
```

When onUpdate is completely commented out, the sprite moves like I want it to, everything is ok. When I put the onUpdate in, the sprite doesn't move at all. I have a feeling that I am overriding the original onUpdate's actions?

Am I going about this the wrong way? I am new to Java, so please feel free to advise if this isn't going to work.

UPDATE: The player2 is the sprite that I'm trying to get the highlighter to follow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're right - you are overriding `SequenceEntityModfier`'s onUpdate method. Simply call parent's onUpdate method when you are overriding it:

```
@Override
public float onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed, IEntity pItem) {
    highlighter.setPosition(player2.getX() - highlighterOffset, player2.getY() - highlighterOffset);
    return super.onUpdate(pSecondsElapsed, pItem);
}
```

Also, it's a good idea to use the `@Override` annotation whenever applicable, because that way you'll know if you are overriding a method or not.

Comment: Doh! I should have looked at the super. in onModifierFinished to figure it out, lol thank you!!